# Преобразование числа в строку

Tags: c++

Как средствами языка с++ преобразовать число в текст и вывести на консоль?
Например:

```
float x = 0.05f;
char *str;

//str = x
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вариант 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

printf("Number is %f\n", x);
```

Вариант 2.

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "Number is " << std::scientific << x << std::endl;
```

Comment: это всё так, но в том и дело, что в str надо записать x и отобразить его...

Comment: Как вариант - воспользоваться sprintf(). Это именно в char *str запишет.

Answer (score 17):

Вот использовать  для конвертирования в С++ методы С вроде atoi,sprintf и т.п.  может быть чревато последствиями. Вот чисто с++-ный вариант на основе потоков, причём универсальный. Можно конвертировать хоть целочисленные типы, хоть с  плавающей точкой.

`

```
#include <string> 
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
std::string toString(T val)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss<< val;
    return oss.str();
}

template<typename T> 
T fromString(const std::string& s) 
{
  std::istringstream iss(s);
  T res;
  iss >> res;
  return res;
}
```

Используется следующим образом

```
std::string str;
int iVal;
float fVal;

str = toString(iVal);
str = tiString(fVal);

iVal = fromString<int>(str);
fVal = fromString<float>(str);
```

Я взял пример отсюда
[Алгоритмы преобразования строки в число и обратно(cyberguru)](http://www.cyberguru.ru/cpp-sources/algorithms/algoritmy-preobrazovaniya-stroki-v-tchislo-i-obratno.html)

Comment: Только в отличии от форматирования в sprintf() совершенно не ясно, каков будет конечный вид.

Comment: почему неясно? toString() - конечный вид string. fromString<КонечныйТип>() - конечный тип указывается в угловых скобках <>, в данном случае конечный тип будет "КонечныйТип".

Comment: Вы не поняли. 

Я имел в виду, какие символы (десятичная точка, знаки плюс/минус и т.п.) и как (размещение в поле вывода) будут выводиться в строку. У форматов sprintf() достаточно богатые возможности, и они видны 'по месту'.

Как нечто подобное реализовать Вашим методом ?

Comment: Я бы этот код назвал плохим. Мне лично непонятна обработка ошибок. Ну, шаблоны это круто, но положим, что во входной строке у нас нет целого числа, а абракадабра. Что будет? Я эту проблему уже тут на ХэшКод решал. Код получился существенно некрасивый. До некоторой степени printf'ы в использовании проще и нагляднее, чем эта шаблонная магия.

P.S. претензия не к toString, а к fromString. С toString все хорошо.

Answer (score 11):

решение в с++11
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/

```
#include <string>

int x = 10;
std::string y = std::to_string(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

Воспользоваться функцией sprintf из stdio.h:

```
float x = 0.05f;
char str[20];
sprintf(str, "%f", x);//или любой другой формат, как это делается в printf()

std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
strstream s;
float x = 0.05f;
s << x; //преобразование в строку
```

upd: ещё можно использовать stringstream

Answer (score 2):

В С++20 можно будет использовать функцию [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format), которая возвращает готовую строку.

Пока поддержки компиляторами не реализовано можно ссылаться через `fmt::`, [например](https://godbolt.org/z/TszGW7edG):

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    float x = 0.05f;
    std::string s = fmt::format("{}", x);
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Переменная `s` совершенно не обязательна и добавлена для наглядности и [желания ТС](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23983/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83#comment23985_23984) иметь результат именно в строке.

Comment: Главный плюс такого решения: количество знаков после точки определяется автоматически.
Есть еще `fmt::to_string(x)`, который делает то же самое.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{

    float a = 33.5;
    int b = 50;
    char str[50];
    _TOSTRING(str, "%f", a);

    cout << str << endl;
    _TOSTRING(str, "%d", b);
    cout << b;

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string flts (long x)
{
    string s;
    char c;
    while(x)
    {
        c=(x%10)+'0';
        s=c+s;
        x=x/10;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score 0):

Я реализовал функцию преобразования числа любого типа в строку таким способом.

value: число которое необходимо преобразовать

radix: система счисления (2/8/10/16)

dec_places: количество знаков после запятой (для вещественного числа)

*если mant_len не указано, то будут преобразованы все знаки, а это не всегда нужно, так как из-за особенностей представления чисел с плавающей запятой результат будет не тот который мы ожидаем.

Например:

 ntos(-0.12) вернет: -0.119999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375

Но если явно указать необходимое количество знаков после запятой, например 2:

ntos(-0.12, 10, 2) вернет: -0.12

```
/**********************************************************************/
/*     Function of converting the number of any type to the string    */
/* ================================================================== */
/* value:      Number to convert                                      */
/* radix:      Numeral system - 2(bin) / 8(oct) / 10(dec) / 16(hex)   */
/* dec_places: Number of the places to the right of the decimal point */
/**********************************************************************/
template<typename T> string ntos(T value, uint8_t radix = 10, int32_t dec_places = -1)
{
    static const char ns[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    string str = "\0";
    switch (radix) {
        case 2:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 16: break;
        default: return str;
    }
    uint8_t mod, index = 0;
    /* Handler for the signed part of the nuber */
    if (value < 0) { /* It is a negative number */
        value = abs(value);
        if (value && dec_places != 0) {
            index = 1;
            str.insert(0, "-");
        } else {
            /* Value less than 0 and decimal places value is 0 */
            str.insert(0, "0");
            return str;
        }
    }
    /* Handler for the unsigned part of the number */
    uint64_t integer = uint64_t(value);
    do { /* Convert an integer part to string */
        mod = integer % radix;
        integer /= radix;
        str.insert(index, (const char*)&ns[mod], 1);
    } while (integer);
    /* Handler for the places to the right of the decimal point of the number */
    value -= (uint64_t)value;  /* Substract an integer part */
    if (value && dec_places != 0) { 
        uint64_t len = 0;
        if (dec_places > 0) {
            /* Rounding */
            uint32_t pow10 = 1;
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < dec_places; i++)
                pow10 *= 10;
            value *= pow10;
            value += 0.5f;
            value /= pow10;
        }
        str += '.';
        do {
            value *= 10;
            integer = (uint64_t)value;
            value -= integer;
            mod = integer % radix;
            integer /= radix;
            str += (const char)ns[mod];
        } while (value && ++len != dec_places);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: В исследовательских целях интересно, но в реальной жизни я бы использовал готовую стандартную функцию или библиотеку.

Comment: Я пишу под микроконтроллеры arm, а для них стандартные функции не всегда подходят, поэтому и приходится придумывать велосипед. В оригинальной функции,  для обеспечения максимальной производительности, например я использовал приведение к uint32_t, а здесь в листинге изменил его на приведение к uint64_t, так как для ПК это не важно.