# Не знаю,как преобразовать тип string в int

Tags: c++, строки, преобразование-типов

Пытался явным преобразованием не получилось:

```
if ((int)temps[i] < min && (int)temps[i]>0)
        {
            min = (int)temps[i];
        }
```

Сама задача:Напишите программу, которая печатает температуру близкую к 0,среди входных данных. Если два числа одинаково близки к нулю, положительное целое число следует рассматривать ближе к нулю (например, если температура -5 и 5, вывести 5).Тип входных данных не менять.
Вот собственно сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void min_temp(int n, string temps)
{
    int min = 5526;
    int min1 = -273;

    for (int i = 0; i < temps.size(); i++)
    {

        if ((int)temps[i] < min && (int)temps[i]>0)
        {
            min = (int)temps[i];
        }
        else if ((int)temps[i] < min1 && (int)temps[i] < 0)
        {
            min1 = (int)temps[i];
        }
    }
    if (min > abs(min1))
    {
        cout << min1<<endl;
    }
    else cout << min<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int n; // the number of temperatures to analyse
    cin >> n;
    string temps;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        getline(cin, temps);
    }

    min_temp(n, temps);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: раз, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23983/Преобразование-числа-в-строку ,  два, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c

Comment: есть такая штука stoi. Вод подробно http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c

Comment: Пробовал я через stoi,он конвертирует всю строку.А я то обращаюсь по элементно и он ругается.

Comment: ну как ,вы запишите то количество символов в отдельную строку и конвертируйте их.

Comment: на самом деле, можно вообще не выполнять конвертацию, из 2 строк (после отрезания минуса если он ест) меньше та, где меньше символов, потом лексикографически.

Comment: каких 2 строк ?:D я не понял)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего в описании вашего задания не указывает, что вы должны использовать объекты типа `std::string`.

Что касается вашего кода, то он бессмысленен. Например, в этом цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) 
{
    getline(cin, temps);
}
```

который имеет `n + 1` итераций, вы при каждой его итерации переписываете значение объекта `temps`. Поэтому в `temps` после выполнения цикла всегда будет находиться то значение, которое вы ввели при последней итерации цикла.

Программа может быть написано проще. В цикле вводятся целочисленные значения и каждое введенное значение сравнивается с текущим значением минимума температуры.

Если же вам необходимо использовать строку, то строка должна содержать разделенные символами пробелов целочисленные значения. Тогда вы можете использовать класс `std::istringstream`, чтобы разбить строку на целые числа и их сравнивать.

Что касается вашего вопроса в заголовке безотносиельно того, что вы написали в самом вопросе,

> Не знаю,как преобразовать тип string в int

то в C++ имеется стандартная функция `stoi`, которая выполняет такое преобразование.

Comment: string обязательно нужен) А вот с циклом не понял,а как тогда заполнить n-ое кол-во значений?

Comment: @SecDet Почему это std::string обязательно нужен? Из описания вашего задания это совершенно не следует.

Comment: Значения ввожу не я,а программа,потом она по тестам гоняет сам код.Скажем так по уставу значения string :)

Comment: @SecDet Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: Хорошо,а по поводу цикла.Как заполнить?В цикле чере cin ?

Comment: @SecDet  Вы можете с помощью одного вызова функции std::getline ввести в строку нужное количество чисел, разделенных пробелами. Либо объявить объект типа std::vector<std::string> и с помощью operator >>  в цикле ввести нужное количество чисел.