# вывести значение переменной на экран

Tags: c++

Задача: вывести значение переменной на экран.
Как сделать? Вот что я написал пока

```
int main() 
{ 
  int peremennaya = 666 
  print(peremennaya)   
}
```

но ничего не работает

Comment: "Вот что я написал" - чем Вы руководствовались, когда так писали?

Comment: точка с запятой отсутствует в обеих строчках,  не   print, а   printf, и аргументы несоответствуют. В двух строках  4 ошибки... Нужно так:   int peremennaya = 666;
    printf("%i", peremennaya);

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование числа в строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23983/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%d", peremennaya);` - Си-шная функция

`cout << peremennaya;` - в стиле C++

Для cout пишем `#include <iostream>`

```
using namespace std;
```

Для printf `#include <stdio.h>`

Директивы `#include` пишем в начале программы

Comment: Я бы сказал: 1) открываем любой учебник по С++ 2) ...

Comment: 1) `using namespace std;` - не очень хорошая вещь. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice 2) `<stdio.h>` - это устаревший вариант. Правильнее: `<cstdio>`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header#C_compatibility_headers

Answer (score 0):

**stdio.h** (от англ. standard input/output header — стандартный заголовочный файл ввода-вывода) - заголовочный файл стандартной библиотеки языка Си, содержащий определения макросов, константы и объявления функций и типов, используемых для различных операций стандартного ввода и вывода

для классических функций типа print**f**();

**iostream** это из С++
заголовочный файл с классами, функциями и переменными для организации ввода-вывода в языке программирования C++. Он включён в стандартную библиотеку C++. Название образовано от Input/Output Stream («поток ввода-вывода»). В языке C++ и его предшественнике, языке программирования Си, нет встроенной поддержки ввода-вывода, вместо этого используется библиотека функций. iostream управляет вводом-выводом, как и stdio.h в Си. iostream используется объекты cin, cout, cerr и clog для передачи информации и из стандартных потоков ввода, вывода, ошибок без буферизации и ошибок с буферизацией соответственно. Являясь частью стандартной библиотеки C++, эти объекты также являются частью стандартного пространства имён — std.

можно использовать одновременно:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
    {
    printf("Hello printf stdio.h");

    using namespace std;
    cout << "Hello cout iostream";

    return 0;
    }
```